# ovverriding a method in hybris provided populator

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to override `addentries` method in `BundleMiniCartPopulator`, in my custom populator.

It gives spring error

> ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] [ModifyPopulatorListBeanPostProcessor] Failed to lookup bean with name [customBundleMiniCartPopulator] trying to add it to populator list [miniCartConverter] org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customBundleMiniCartPopulator' defined in class path resource [pilfacades-spring.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'promotionResultConverter' of bean class [com.custom.b2c.ecommerce.facades.order.converters.populators.customBundleMiniCartPopulator]: Bean property 'promotionResultConverter' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

I tried injecting promotionresultconverter in my populator and generated setter method too. But still I am getting same error.     Can some one tell me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: bean declaration :<bean  id ="customBundleMiniCartPopulator"  parent ="defaultBundleMiniCartPopulator"
        class="com.philips.b2c.ecommerce.facades.order.converters.populators.CustomBundleMiniCartPopulator">

Comment: Have you declared promotionResultConverter property in your bean definition ?

Comment: Please add your Spring definition + class BundleMiniCartPopulator. It seems like a naming issue.

Answer (score 0):

If we go up through the Spring bean parents of the above declared bean(bean with id="customBundleMiniCartPopulator): 
"defaultBundleMiniCartPopulator" is the child of "abstractBundleOrderPopulator" which is the child of "defaultAbstractSubscriptionOrderPopulator" which is the child of "baseOrderPopulator"

Now "baseOrderPopulator" bean injects the mentioned property (promotionResultConverter).

Bean definition(which includes promotionResultConverter property) can be seen bellow(commercefacades-spring.xml):

```
<bean id="baseOrderPopulator"
        class="de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.order.converters.populator.AbstractOrderPopulator"
        abstract="true">
    <property name="promotionResultConverter" ref="promotionResultConverter"/>
    <property name="promotionsService" ref="promotionsService"/>
    <property name="modelService" ref="modelService"/>
    <property name="addressConverter" ref="addressConverter"/>
    <property name="deliveryModeConverter" ref="deliveryModeConverter"/>
    <property name="zoneDeliveryModeConverter" ref="zoneDeliveryModeConverter"/>
    <property name="creditCardPaymentInfoConverter" ref="creditCardPaymentInfoConverter"/>
    <property name="orderEntryConverter" ref="orderEntryConverter"/>
    <property name="priceDataFactory" ref="priceDataFactory"/>
    <property name="commonI18NService" ref="commonI18NService"/>
    <property name="typeService" ref="typeService"/>
    <property name="principalConverter" ref="principalConverter"/>
</bean>
```

The Java class associated to the above bean(i.e AbstractOrderPopulator) has the field(promotionResultConverter), and associated getter, and setter:

```
protected Converter<PromotionResultModel, PromotionResultData> getPromotionResultConverter()
{
    return promotionResultConverter;
}

@Required
public void setPromotionResultConverter(final Converter<PromotionResultModel, PromotionResultData> promotionResultConverter)
{
    this.promotionResultConverter = promotionResultConverter;
}
```

As a conclusion there is no need to create field, setter and bean property(pilfacades-spring.xml) since
    the JAVA class AbstractOrderPopulator (which you inherit) already has the field and
    the bean with id="baseOrderPopulator" (which you inherit) already has properly configured the property.